# Download and launch default app in windows phone 8 in C#

Tags: c#, live, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I am using **Live api** to download **SkyDrive** files.

My code has a download click event which triggers the **OnDownloadedCompleted function.**

OnDownloadedCompleted function copies the file to "filename".

and calls the DefaultLaunch(), which takes in the "filename" and tries to launch it by the default program in windows phone 8.

When i **execute** this code (The file downloaded is a OneNote file) **OneNote opens and says that the file can't be open.**

Can anyone please help me validate this code?

**Thanks a lot!**

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (App.Current.LiveSession == null)
        {
            infoTextBlock.Text = "You must sign in first.";
        }
        else
        {
            LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(App.Current.LiveSession);
            client.DownloadCompleted += new EventHandler<LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs>(OnDownloadCompleted);

            client.DownloadAsync("file_id");

        }
    }
```

The code for OnDownloadCompleted is

```
void OnDownloadCompleted(object sender, LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result != null)
        {
            var filestream = File.Create(@"filename");
            e.Result.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            e.Result.CopyTo(filestream);
            filestream.Close();
            DefaultLaunch();

            e.Result.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            infoTextBlock.Text = "Error downloading image: " + e.Error.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The code for Default launch function is

```
 async void DefaultLaunch()
    {

        try
        {
            string imageFile = @"File.one";
            var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);
            var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
            if (success)
            {}
            else
            {}
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Comment: How is `"filename"` and `"File.one"` the same filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this tutorial.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/ff519582.aspx.. it is given there how to use live sdk in windows 8 platform

Comment: Hey actually i tried using a test data and gave the name File.one. Its actually filename.

Comment: zedray - can you please be specific. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hey i implemented the code by putting the "/content" after the file id. Now it is working, However I am able not able to open ".onepkg" format files. Ideally they should open in OneNote but it asks me to find an app in the store. any suggestions/pointers?  Thanks for your help!